# R1C1 array formula based on Row Count

Tags: vba, excel

```
ws.Range("E1").FormulaArray = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(Source!R1C3:R591C3,MATCH(Components!RC3,IF(Source!R1C1:R591C1=Components!R25C,Source!R1C2:R591C2),0))),0,1)"
```

I have this, how do I change the dynamic reference 591 to L?

```
L = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the variable name into the string - not so that it's part of the string, but rather its value is.

Whereever you want to replace `591` with `L` break out of the string text using `"`, add your variable `& L &` and then step back into the string with another `"`.

So `...Source!R1C3:R" & L & "C3....`

Comment: Thanks @Darren, String was missing